# Could not find any version that matches com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:12+ (

Tags: android, angular, cordova, ionic-framework, sdk

I'm trying to compile on ionic 3.20 with cordova 6.5.0 on Android.

I'm executing `cordova run android` but everytime I'm getting:

```
Error: ~/Develop/blastbot-ionic/platforms/android/gradlew: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.
 Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':_debugApkCopy'.
   > Could not find any version that matches com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:12+.
 Versions that do not match:
     11.0.4
     11.0.2
     11.0.1
     11.0.0
     10.2.6
     + 18 more
 Required by:
     :android:unspecified

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
```

I have all this installed:
[SDK Manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WNYWx.png)

I've already tried executing `cordova platform rm android` & `cordova platform rm android@6.2` or `cordova platform rm android`. Both ending in the same result. Downloaded a million different SDK's versions.

Comment: Is there a way to not-require such old versions of play-services?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried `cordova platform add android@5` and afterwards `cordova run android` and it worked like a charm.

*UPDATE*

The line abov "solved" the issue partially, but my targeted API level was 23 instead of 25. The issue, after almost month and a half of trying different SDK tools/build-tools/Google repo combinations I found the solution.

Navigate to `platforms/android/project.properties` and look for a line like 
`cordova.system.library.2=com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:12+`

Notice that `12+` at the end. Simply change it to `11+`, that will do the job. Hope nobody goes through this like I did.